# Preserving html tags in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to preserve html tags using xslt. For example I have xml structure: 
    `<adaptation>
      <body>
        <p>
          <t>Consultez l'offre de formation en ligne (en cliquant sur le niveau souhaité dans le schéma ci-dessous)</t>
        </p>
      </body>
     </adaptation>`.

I want to preserve the tags `<body>, <p>`... I tried to use copy-of, but it doesn't work:

```
`<xsl:template name="insertInfo">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:param name="objet"/>
    <xsl:param name="valeurInfo"/>

    <xsl:text>INSERT INTO Information(idObjet, objetNom, valeurInfo)  VALUES (" </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
    <xsl:text>", "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$objet"/>
    <xsl:text>", "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$valeurInfo"/>

    <xsl:text>");&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template> `

`<xsl:variable name="valeurInfo">
<xsl:value-of select="./adaptation"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:call-template name="insertInfo">
    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="$idObjet" />
<xsl:with-param name="objet" select="$noeud" />
<xsl:with-param name="valeurInfo" select="$valeurInfo"/>
 </xsl:call-template>`.
```

I even tried to use copy-of when I'm creating the var "valeurInfo". The result is just a text.
Thank you for help.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful. You need to show an example of the input XML you're working from and the output you want, and explain how this differs from the output you're currently getting.

Comment: Your XSLT code is insufficient and it doesn't have any template that does something. What is your desired output? Give us a sample.

Comment: I need to obtain in output: <body>
        <p>
          <t>Consultez l'offre de formation en ligne (en cliquant sur le niveau souhaité dans le schéma ci-dessous)</t>
        </p>
      </body>.
At the moment, my output is: Consultez l'offre de formation en ligne (en cliquant sur le niveau souhaité dans le schéma ci-dessous)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="valeurInfo">
  <xsl:value-of select="./adaptation"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

will set the variable to the *string value* of the `adaptation` element, which means the concatenation of all it's descendant text nodes without intervening tags. If instead you say

```
<xsl:variable name="valeurInfo" select="./adaptation"/>
```

then this will make the variable hold a reference to the `adaptation` element node itself, rather than the element's value.

If you want just the content inside the `adaptation` element but not the `<adaptation>...</adaptation>` tags themselves then try

```
<xsl:variable name="valeurInfo" select="./adaptation/node()"/>
```

Comment: I have the same result: INSERT INTO Information(idObjet, objetNom, typeInfo, valeurInfo) VALUES ("ME3FPS", "mention", "adaptation", "
      
        
          Consultez l'offre de formation en ligne (en cliquant sur le niveau souhaité dans le schéma ci-dessous)
        
      
    "); - without tags <body> or <p>